# Creating table layout and assigning a list to it

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-tablelayout, custom-adapter

I want to achieve a layout like below for my application.

[image]

Iam thinking of using a `TableLayout` for the same. I also have a list which has a Image and two textviews which I need to display in each of the cell.

Can anyone help me out on how I can assign a list and a custom adapter to the above design.

Thanks

Comment: you can implement this design with help of list only. Create custom layout as per your design and inflate that layout into your getview(). And set the values as per its position to particular view.

Comment: @chet's can you give  me aexample

Comment: you are getting data from server??

Comment: @Chet's yes the data comes from the server

Answer (score 0):

Prepare proper data structure for your design. Generate getter setter as given below and inside your application Create Arraylist of this class and pass it to your custom adapter class. And as per position set values to particular view (e.g i have consider textview as example).

```
public class TableValues {

private String text1,text2,text3,text4,text5;

public String getText1() {
    return text1;
}

public void setText1(String text1) {
    this.text1 = text1;
}

public String getText2() {
    return text2;
}

public void setText2(String text2) {
    this.text2 = text2;
}

public String getText3() {
    return text3;
}

public void setText3(String text3) {
    this.text3 = text3;
}

public String getText4() {
    return text4;
}

public void setText4(String text4) {
    this.text4 = text4;
}

public String getText5() {
    return text5;
}

public void setText5(String text5) {
    this.text5 = text5;
}
```

}